# How to make Project installation setup like VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, blend

Today i installed vs 2012, I have seen the installations setup  is very nice. Is any possibility to make Project installation setup like VS 2012?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think that setup is built with WiX, as a bundle that wraps several separate MSI files, and with custom bootstrapper UI. I think there's a vdProj to WiX converter that creates a WiX install file, but I've not used it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Laika42 Themed Boostrapper`:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6e84def3-9f27-4292-aa3b-3ec542338e4a

**Update:**

Just found out that this product has got a new name `Visual Installer`. Product site is [here](http://www.xeam-solutions.com/products/visual-installer.html).

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you wish to create these kind of windows or are you searching for an app, which wrapps your setup (like installshield....).

if the first one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx